# Trying to put an AsyncTask class in a util package/class for I/O operations

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

Here is what I'm trying to accomplish. First, I know my application is going to do a lot of I/O. I have read that it's not a good idea to perform this on the main thread. I have seen it recommended that we should use background threads for this. I know we can use `Service`s but I think using `AsyncTask` would be cleaner and make more sense for my particular application. I have created a package in my project named 'util' where I place a class called FileHelper. This class is going to contain methods to perform most of my I/O operations for the app. This means I will need to pass in a `Context` object. I just have a question about implementation. I have started constructing my class like this:

```
public class FileHelper {

    public static Match createMatchFromFile(String fileName) {

        File file = new File(fileName);
        String jsonString = "";

        if (file.exists()) {
            BufferedReader reader = null;

            try {
                reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
                jsonString = reader.readLine();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (reader != null) {
                        reader.close();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, Match.class);
    }

    public static boolean writeMatchToFile(Context context, String filename, String jsonString){

        context = context.getApplicationContext();

        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        File file = new File(filename);

        try {
            fos = context.openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            fos.write(jsonString.getBytes());
            return true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        } finally {
            try {
                assert fos != null;
                fos.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static class WriteMatchToFile extends AsyncTask<Match, Void, Void>{

        Context mContext;

        public WriteMatchToFile(Context context) {

            mContext = context.getApplicationContext();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Match... matches) {

            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

look at the static class of WriteMatchToFile. I'm using an AsyncTask. I want to call it from the Activity like this:

new FileHelper.WriteMatchToFile(Context context).execute(Match match);

I don't want to place this method in an Activity because I will be calling it throughout the entire application. The problem is 'Lint' is yelling at me and telling me that I'm leaking the context in the WriteMatchToFile class. It's saying that "Non-static inner classes have a implicit reference to their outer classes." But I thought I defined this AsyncTask as statc?!?

Is there a better way to implement this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its yelling at you because you potentially are-  threads holding onto a Context will prevent that Context from being GCed until the thread ends.  If your thread is doing something like short lived disk IO (reading/writing a file) that's ok and you can ignore this warning.  It will only hold up gcing it for a few hundred ms.  If its doing some long term processing, then you should look for a way to only hold the Context as long as possible.  Also if its long term, you should use a Thread instead of AsyncTask, as an AsyncTask will hold up other AsyncTasks.

Your usage here appears fine, the write to disk is relatively quick.

Comment: Will my static classes remain in memory? Or after being executed will they get GCed?

Comment: static classes are just  inner classes that don't have an implicit reference to the parent.  They get GCed when they have no further references to them, like any other class.

Comment: so is it safe to assume if I call it like this: new FileHelper.WriteMatchToFile(context).execute(Match);     after it executes, sense I have no variable that references it, it should be GCed?

Comment: Yes, it should be available to be collected as soon as it finishes executing (until then it will have a reference in the framework, either in the list of tasks queued for execution, or as a running task).

Comment: Is it possible, if I'm using a similar method to read a file back in, and having this AsyncTask in a util package, to return a value from the AsycnTask method so I can construct a new Match object without defining the AsyncTask class in my Activity?

Answer (score 0):

You have done the right thing by making it static. If you can avoid passing context then avoid it but if it is necessary then you should use

```
public static class WriteMatchToFile extends AsyncTask<Match, Void, Void>{

    WeakReference<Context> mContextReference;

    public WriteMatchToFile(Context context) {

        mContextReference = new WeakReference<Context> (context.getApplicationContext());
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Match... matches) {

        return null;
    }
}
```

Also be careful which type of context do you need application or activity. In case of Application context you could make a singleton class that extends your application and directly call className.getApplicationContext() from it.

Comment: Thanks, I should use WeakReference! I use the ApplicationContext because I don't want to pass an Activitie's context and have the thread referencing it while it runs.